# With AVAudioSession can I play to headphones and record from the front facing mic?

Tags: ios, ios7, avaudiosession

I can do this if the user plugs in a normal set of headphones. But if the user plugs in a set of headphones that have the integrated mic, then that is used for recording.

If I set [AVAudioSession setPreferredInput:error:] to the iPhone front mic, then the audio output comes out the iPhone speaker.

[AVAudioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:error:] only has options for speaker and none. Is there anyway to override to the headphones?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set `automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession` property to NO on the AVCaptureSession you use to record?

See the relevant note in the [iOS docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringanAudioSession/ConfiguringanAudioSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH2-SW9).